# Access VBA: Run-time error 94 Invalid use of Null

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have this error in Access VBA:

> Run-time error '94': Invalid use of Null

```
Me!total.Text = Nz(Val(weight.Value) * Nz(Val(takeem.Column(0))) / 100) _
              + Nz(Val(weight2.Value) * Nz(Val(takeem2.Column(0))) / 100) _
              + Nz(Val(weight3.Value) * Nz(Val(takeem3.Column(0))) / 100) _
              + Nz(Val(weight4.Value) * Nz(Val(takeem4.Column(0))) / 100)
```

I tried using the `Nz` function but it's still not working.

Comment: @FlorentB.: `myCombobox.Column(0)` is correct syntax to refer to the first column of the selected combobox (or listbox) item.

Comment: Also make sure you really want `Me!total.Text`.  The `.Text` property is only available when `Me!total` has focus.  It could be the right choice for your situation.  But if you're getting an error with `.Text` (after you implement Andre's suggestions), see whether `Me!total.Value` works better.

Answer (score 4):

`Val()` doesn't accept NULL values. So you must use `Nz()` as inner function, and `Val()` as outer function.

It's also always a good idea to specify the second parameter of `Nz()` - in your case, since you are calculating, it's probably `0`.

```
Me!total.Text = Val(Nz(weight.Value, 0)) * Val(Nz(takeem.Column(0), 0)) / 100
' etc
```